# Why following queries have different output?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-order-by

Even though `2*3-5 = 1` why do both these queries have different output?

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY 1 asc, column2 desc;
```

vs.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY 2*3-5 asc, column2 desc;
```

Comment: Ordering by column ordinal is a practice best avoided anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort by first column in resultset and then by `column2`

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY 1 asc, column2 desc;
```

Sort by constant expression and `column2`:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY 2*3-5 asc, column2 desc;
<=>
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column2 desc;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/920ac7/4/2)**</kbd>

> [**ORDER BY { column-Name | ColumnPosition | Expression }**](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj13658.html)
>
> *ColumnPosition*
>
> An integer that identifies the number of the column in the SelectItems in the underlying query of the SELECT statement.
>   ColumnPosition must be greater than 0 and not greater than the number
>   of columns in the result table. In other words, if you want to order
>   by a column, that column must be specified in the SELECT list.

Keep in mind that in some RDBMS ordering by constant is not allowed like `SQL Server`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab
ORDER BY 2*3-5 asc, column2 desc;
-- A constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list, position 1.
```

Comment: Are the following equivalent                                                                    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY 2*3-5 asc, column2 desc;
<=>
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column2 desc, column1 asc;

Comment: @sql_dummy `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY 2*3-5 asc, column2 desc;` IS NOT EQUIVALENT TO `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column2 desc, column1 asc;`

Comment: so what happens to the columns that are represented by an expression? Are they simply ignored?

Comment: @sql_dummy When the expression is **constant** (2*3-5), each row has the same value so sort by this expression does not affect final resultset. Keep in mind that the expression may depend on value in row, then it will affect sorting e.g. `ORDER BY MOD(id, 2)`

Comment: In SQL Server `ORDER BY (SELECT 2*3-5) asc, column2 desc;` would probably be allowed. But still be pointless.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes it is allowed, and I sometimes use it with windowed functions as placeholder like: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))`

Comment: @lad2025 for all the examples I tried, I find SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY 2*3-5 asc, column2 desc; <==> TO SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column2 desc, column1 asc;http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d45b0/1

Comment: @sql_dummy **No, no and once more no.** The queries `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY 2*3-5 asc, column2 desc;` **!=**   `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column2 desc, column1` See **[counterexample demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91406/1/2)** The columm1 has `4-2-6-1` (not `2-4-1-6`).